# Неверный тип данных sqlite3

Tags: python, telegram-bot, sqlite, sqlite3

при вводе данных через телеграмм бот в столбец с типом INTEGER пролетает текст

```
def setup(self):
    tblincome = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS income (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, date TIMESTAMP, category TEXT, price INTEGER)"
    tbloutcome = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS outcome (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, date TIMESTAMP , category TEXT, price INTEGER)"
    self.conn.execute(tblincome)
    self.conn.execute(tbloutcome)
    self.conn.commit()
```

Вот сам код для добавления записи

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def sigarette_usage(message):
    try:
        today = date.today().strftime("%d.%m.%Y")
        price = message.text
        text_message = f'На {today} в таблицу расходов добавлена запись: тип "Сигареты", сумма {price} грн'
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text_message)
        db.add_item_outcome(today, 'Сигареты', price)
```

[image: результат]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В Sqlite3 тип столбца не определяет тип хранимого значения в этом поле записи, то есть в любой столбец можно занести любое значение. Допустим, мы объявили столбец как `«A INTEGER»`.
SQlite позволяет занести в этот столбец значения любого типа `(999, «abc», «123», 678.525)`.
Если вставляемое значение — не целое, то SQlite пытается привести его к целому.
Т.е. строка `«123»` превратится в целое `123`, а остальные значения запишутся `«как есть»`.

Comment: Совершенно верно. [Datatypes In SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).

Answer (score 0):

Я не очень понял суть вопроса, но может быть так:

```
try: 
    price = int(message.text)
except:
    print("Видимо это не число...")
```